# Is there any string size limit in POST request?

Tags: python-3.x, api, rest

I have to make a POST API (python), where the APP will send the encoded string of a file(base64 encoding) in the request body. But, for a large file, the string length can be very large. Thus, wanting to know if this will cause any issue for large files?
Example:

```
{
  filename:"abc.pdf",
  encoded_string: "{{very large encoded string}}"
}
```

A few other related questions are:

1. Is there any size limit for encoded_string for making POST API requests?
2. Is there any better approach to handle this large string?

Comment: Just put the raw file in the request body to save 33%. You could compress the file to make it even smaller

Comment: @Evert, I need to send a base64 encoded string only.